# Eclipse Editor - hiding parts of a line

Tags: eclipse-plugin, text-editor

I build my Text Editor in Eclipse.

Is there a way of hiding part of a line in Eclipse Editor Plugin?
Currently I am using ProjectionViewer as a SourceViewer and it can only hide (fold) whole lines, and not part of a line.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without ProjetionViewer but to still have ability to fold lines?